# ¿Cómo mantener abierto un proceso al cerrar la sesión SSH?

Tags: linux

Resulta que tengo un proceso que me gustaría mantener abierto durante un tiempo indefinido. Si inicio el proceso desde SSH, al salir de la sesión SSH el proceso también se cierra.

Quiero saber cómo se puede dejar ese proceso ejecutándose aunque salga de la sesión SSH.

Comment: Deberías replantear tu respuesta correcta por esta otra: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/218977/18608](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/218977/18608). No necesitas mantener una sesión de shell abierta para un programa que se ejecuta en segundo plano sin interacción con el usuario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aclaraciones:

1. `tmux` y `screen` no son principalmente para eso que quieres, son un multiplexor y un emulador de terminal respectivamente. Que te permitan mantener un proceso ejecutándose en un servidor remoto no es su característica principal. Utilizarlos sólo para eso es subutilizarlos y dejar corriendo en tu servidor remoto programas de más.
2. A diferencia de lo que dijo @patapalo, el caracter '&' no mantiene un proceso abierto después de cerrar sesión. Lo que hace es que lo pasa a background permitiendo que la shell desde la que se ejecutó continue trabajando. Si cierras la conexión ssh este proceso se para.

Lo que necesitas es el programa `nohup` que está diseñado para eso.

La forma de correr nohup es la siguiente:

```
nohup ./programa &
```

Lo que hace `nohup` hacer que un programa ignore la señal SIGHUP. Cuando uno corre un programa y luego se sale de la terminal, aunque lo haya corrido en background con `./programa &`, el programa recibe una señal SIGHUP lo cual suspende la ejecución del programa. En cambio, con `nohup` puedes seguir corriendo el programa a pesar de cerrar la sesión ssh o enviar una señal como `kill -1 pid_del_programa`.

Para matarlo sólo tienes que matar el proceso asociado al programa, ya sea con kill (claro, siempre y cuando no envíes la señal 1 o `SIGHUP`) o con algún visor de procesos, etc.

Comment: Creo que esta debería ser la respuesta correcta, ya que si necesita ejecutarse de fondo sin interacción con el usuario, es completamente innecesario mantener la sesión de shell abierta con `screen` o `tmux`.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes ejecutar el proceso utilizando `screen`:

```
SCREEN comando Argumentos
```

y luego haces un detach/separas de `screen` presionado <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> y luego <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Después puedes cerrar la sessión SSH.

Answer (score 2):

Yo te recomendaría usar [`tmux`](https://tmux.github.io/) (**t**erminal **mu**ltiple**x**er), es más moderno y tiene algunas ventajas sobre `screen`.

### Ventajas

De acuerdo al [FAQ](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/FAQ):

- Usa un modelo cliente-servidor
- Diferentes interfaces de comandos
- Puede ser extendido
- Es posible limitar el tamaño de la ventana
- Tiene soporte para búsqueda
- El modelo para la división de ventanas (split) es diferente. `tmux` cuenta con dos objetos, ventana y panel; `screen` solo tiene ventanas.

### Uso

Ten en cuenta que debes ejecutar `tmux` en el servidor al cual te conectas a través de SSH, en los ejemplos estoy asumiendo que ya te has conectado.

Por defecto, `tmux` usa la combinación <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> como un atajo para ejecutar los comandos, pero para los ejemplos haré uso de los comandos sin atajos.

Es preferible nombrar tus sesiones para mantener el orden, con el siguiente ejemplo sencillo puedes crear una nueva sesión:

```
$ tmux new -s prueba
```

Bien, ya tienes una sesión a la cual podrías regresar incluso despues de haberte desconectado y encontrar todo tal y como lo dejaste, probemos esto ejecutando un simple comando:

```
$ pwd
/home/cesar
```

Para salir de la sesión (detach):

```
$ tmux detach
```

Y deberías regresar a la parte inicial en donde creaste la sesión:

```
$ tmux new -s prueba
[detached]
$
```

Puedes ver las sesiones activas:

```
$ tmux ls
prueba: 1 windows (created Mon Feb 15 08:32:51 2016) [151x36]
```

Para entrar nuevamente a la sesión (attach):

```
$ tmux attach -t prueba
```

Y ahora deberías encontrar las cosas como las dejaste la última vez (incluyendo el comando `tmux detach`):

```
$ pwd
/home/cesar
$ tmux detach
$
```

Si quieres terminar la sesión (kill):

```
$ tmux kill-session -t prueba
```

Ya no deberían haber sesiones:

```
$ tmux ls
failed to connect to server
```

Bien, estos son algunos comandos básicos que muestran las bondades de `tmux`, aunque como comentaba más arriba es incluso más rápido usar los comandos usando atajos con <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.

### Referencias

- [Sitio oficial](https://tmux.github.io/)
- [Manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1)
- [Repositorio en GitHub](https://github.com/tmux/tmux)

Comment: Mucho mejor explicado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo consigo que  un comando continue ejecutandose añadiedo un & al final.

Creo que es como decirle que se ejecute en background y no se ejecute en el shell del ssh

Por ejemplo java -jar xxx.jar &

Comment: Eso deja al proceso en segundo plano. Pero si lo ejecutas desde una conexión remota y cierras la conexión, ese proceso se detiene. Como comentan lo suyo es utilizar nohup